# Serverless framework SQS RedrivePolicy on a deadLetterTargetArn fails on first deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

While deploying with serverless framework a SQS queue attached to a DLQ I have this error

It's kind of strange because it seem's to deploy correctly when my DLQ and SQS queue are already deployed and I only add RedrivePolicy in my serverless.ts file (seem's to be the RedrivePolicy that he don't likes)

But when I deploy at first like this I have a CREATE_FAILED with this error

CloudFormation error

```bash
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: Error occurred while
ReceiveMessage. SQS Error Code: AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue. SQS Error Message:
The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version.
(Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400)
(HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

serverless.ts

```js
import type { AWS } from '@serverless/typescript';

// Lambdas
import getMessage from './src/functions/add-to-pros';

const serverlessConfiguration: AWS = {
  service: 'dlq-service',
  frameworkVersion: '3',
  custom: {
    stageType: '${opt:stage, env:AWS_STAGE, "dev"}',
    envType: '${env:ENV_TYPE, "dev"}',
    apiDomainName: 'api.${self:custom.hostedZoneName}',
    apiBasePath: 'api-${self:custom.stageType}-${self:service}',

    // SQS Queues
    getMessageQueue: 'GetMessageQueue',
    getMessageQueueName: '${self:service}-add-to-pros-queue-${self:provider.stage}',
    getMessageQueueArn: {
      'Fn::Join': [':', ['arn', 'aws', 'sqs', { Ref: 'AWS::Region' }, { Ref: 'AWS::AccountId' }, '${self:custom.getMessageQueueName}']],
    },
    getMessageQueueDLQ: 'GetMessageQueueDLQ',
    getMessageQueueDLQName: '${self:service}-add-to-pros-queue-dlq-${self:provider.stage}',

    esbuild: {
      bundle: true,
      minify: false,
      sourcemap: true,
      exclude: ['aws-sdk'],
      target: 'node16',
      define: { 'require.resolve': undefined },
      platform: 'node',
      concurrency: 10,
      loader: { '.html': 'text' },
    },
  },
  plugins: ['serverless-esbuild', 'serverless-deployment-bucket', 'serverless-offline'],
  provider: {
    name: 'aws',
    runtime: 'nodejs16.x',
    stage: '${self:custom.stageType}',
    region: 'eu-west-3',
    deploymentBucket: {
      name: '${self:service}-${self:custom.envType}-${self:provider.region}-deployment-bucket-2',
    },
  },
  functions: {
    getMessage,
  },
  package: {
    // When true optimise lambda performance but increase deployment time
    individually: !!process.env.STAGE_TYPE && process.env.STAGE_TYPE !== 'dev',
  },
  resources: {
    Resources: {
      // Dead Letter Queues
      GetMessageQueueDLQ: {
        Type: 'AWS::SQS::Queue',
        Properties: {
          QueueName: '${self:custom.getMessageQueueDLQName}',
          MessageRetentionPeriod: 1209600, // 14 days in seconds
        },
      },

      // Queues
      GetMessageQueue: {
        DependsOn: ['${self:custom.getMessageQueueDLQ}'],
        Type: 'AWS::SQS::Queue',
        Properties: {
          QueueName: '${self:custom.getMessageQueueName}',
          RedrivePolicy: {
            deadLetterTargetArn: {
              'Fn::GetAtt': ['${self:custom.getMessageQueueDLQ}', 'Arn'],
            },
            maxReceiveCount: 3,
          },
          VisibilityTimeout: 900,
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

module.exports = serverlessConfiguration;
```

getMessage lambda src/functions/handler.ts

```js
export async function main(event: SQSEvent): Promise<void> {
  try {
    logger.info(event);
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(error);
  }
}
```

getMessage lambda src/functions/index.ts

```js
import { getCurrentFolderPath } from '@libs/utils/handler-resolver';

export default {
  handler: `${getCurrentFolderPath(__dirname)}/handler.main`,
  memorySize: 256,
  events: [
    {
      sqs: {
        arn: '${self:custom.getMessageQueueArn}',
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand why but the error was not RedrivePolicy but the lambda events

Replace this

```js
import { getCurrentFolderPath } from '@libs/utils/handler-resolver';

export default {
  handler: `${getCurrentFolderPath(__dirname)}/handler.main`,
  memorySize: 256,
  events: [
    {
      sqs: {
        arn: '${self:custom.getMessageQueueArn}',
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

By that

```js
import { getCurrentFolderPath } from '@libs/utils/handler-resolver';

export default {
  handler: `${getCurrentFolderPath(__dirname)}/handler.main`,
  memorySize: 256,
  events: [
    {
      sqs: {
        arn: {
          'Fn::GetAtt': ['${self:custom.getMessageQueue}', 'Arn'],
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Would appreciate if someone explain it to me ?